# Hide div at breakpoint using predefined grid classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three divs. On a full-screen device each column is 33% of the parent div 'row' which is as I expect. When the screen is resized to be smaller I would like div B to disappear so that div A and C expand to nest beside each other at 50% each.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-0">B</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">C</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible using notation like `col-sm-0` or must I manually write a media query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v4 beta there exist [new hiding classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-3 d-sm-none">B</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `hidden` classes:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

You could use `hidden-sm` in your case.

Bootstrap 4:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

You could use `hidden-sm-down` in your case.